# Reading data with EF 6 in a Singleton Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, scope, dbcontext, .net-6.0

I'm working on a .Net 6 API that uses a Service Layer to do all the business logic of the Controllers. And I'm trying to use EF 6 on this layer using the "using" statement to be able to use de dbContext in a Singleton class. The problem is that once all the logic has been done and the Controller is mapping the object I get a "disposed object" error.

The Service Method

```
        public async Task<StudiesResponse> GetAllStudies()
        {
            StudiesResponse studies = new StudiesResponse();
            List<StudyReponse> list = new List<StudyReponse>();
            StudyReponse resp;
            try
            {
                using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var _dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                    foreach (Study study in _dbContext.Studies)
                    {
                        resp = new StudyReponse()
                        {
                            StudyCode = study.IXRSStudyCode,
                            Participators =  _dbContext.RoleUsers.Where(x => x.Study.StudyId == study.StudyId).Select(x => new ParticipatorsResponse()
                            {
                                UserEmail = x.User.UserEmail, 
                                RoleName = x.Role.Name
                            })
                        };
                        list.Add(resp);
                    }
                }
                studies.Studies = list;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { throw e; }

            return studies;
        }
```

My problem is that in the line "list.Add(resp);" my list of Participators is still with all the data. But once the code leaves the Using, the property Participators of the list variable is empty... I understand that the problem is that I'm getting it from the LinQ result from the _dbContext and it gets disposed. BUT I don't know why... I mean, I'm assigning it to a variable, why it's not sticking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `ToList()` after `.Select(x => new ParticipatorsResponse() {  })` to persist the `Participators` collection.

This is because the data is "lazy" and is only retrieved when iterating the the collection.

Since you iterate it outside the using block (probably where you call `GetAllStudies()`), the connection is not valid anymore. The `ToList()` iterates it and stores a list instead of a `IEnumerable/IQueryable`.

```
resp = new StudyReponse()
{
    StudyCode = study.IXRSStudyCode,
    Participators =  _dbContext.RoleUsers.Where(x => x.Study.StudyId == study.StudyId).Select(x => new ParticipatorsResponse()
    {
        UserEmail = x.User.UserEmail, 
        RoleName = x.Role.Name
    }).ToList()
};
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue. Thank you very much, this looks a bit silly.

Comment: Not only the problem is solved, you now also know why it failed.  \o/